# Need help to convert gml child to one autocad polyline with vb.net

Tags: .net, autocad, gml-geographic-markup-lan

Need help to convert next gml child to one autocad polyline with vb.net

```
<imgeo:geometrie2dVegetatieObject><gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:exterior><gml:Ring><gml:curveMember><gml:Curve><gml:segments><gml:LineStringSegment><gml:posList srsDimension="2">97681.158 454458.772 97681.244 454457.112 97681.410 454445.200 97681.530 454444.900 97681.590 454444.630 97687.590 454434.370 97687.769 454434.013 97687.876 454434.015 97688.768 454433.957 97688.439 454434.261 97688.090 454434.331 97682.080 454445.372 97681.731 454457.462 97681.789 454458.350</gml:posList></gml:LineStringSegment><gml:Arc><gml:posList srsDimension="2">97681.789 454458.350 97681.478 454458.574 97681.158 454458.772</gml:posList></gml:Arc></gml:segments></gml:Curve></gml:curveMember></gml:Ring></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></imgeo:geometrie2dVegetatieObject>
```

I can create an separate Arcs and polyline but need them both in one polyline before I read next child